# AIR nativeprocess performance

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

Is AIR `nativeprocess` able to receive message from Java program and process every line of message as fast as possible in milliseconds? Does it has a miss read or delay?

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with the AIR NativeProcess to java.  I haven't compared its performance with sockets, but my 2 cents would be that the NativeProcess would give you better performance as I believe it's based on IPC (pipes)...which is a shared memory based technique (although, not sure what's under the covers if socket comms to a local process)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use the AIR NativeProcess to launch a Java app that listens on a Socket.  Then the AIR app connects to that Socket to communicate with the Java app.  The [Merapi Project](http://www.merapiproject.net/) sets all of this up for you.

Comment: Is that still faster? I've been using NativeProcess to communicate to a python script that's listening for serial input, as an alternative to using sockets - I'm almost done building it, haven't done a speed test yet. Sockets are still going to be better?

Comment: I'm pretty sure sockets will be faster than STDOUT.  But I don't have data to back that up.

Comment: Hi James ward, would you mind to test that? I will looking forward to see your blog. It is important to make the right one since I will need to handle lot of data from MIDI :D

Comment: I won't have a chance to test that for a while but I'm pretty confident that Sockets is the way to go.